# Different result param name in XML with different property name in Action

Tags: struts2

The below code works well to download a file.

Here name of the param is `inputName` in xml and property in Action is `fileInputStream`.I don't know how it works with different name in xml and Action.

**XML :**

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
  <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="fileABC.txt"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

**Action :**

```
private InputStream fileInputStream;     
    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    } 
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\downloadfile.txt"));
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"different name in xml and Action"*?

Answer (score 0):

Param name `inputName` indicate name of your stream object.

See this [Doc refrence](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/stream-result.html):

`inputName - the name of the InputStream property from the chained action

(default = inputStream).`

param name `inputName` is not related to your variable name in action class, instead its value is related to your variable present in your action class.